# force logout use identityserver4 like facebook where you're logged in

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, refresh-token

Here is my case:
 I have two server. one is MVC, another is Auth. Auth server use identityServer4 to integrate the SSO. MVC is a client which should login.
I use the HybridAndClientCredentials GrantTypes for the MVC client.
The MVC website have a page like facebook Where You're logged in. It can list the account where it logged in and use what device. All this is fine.

Is there a way to force log out other's device like facebook?

I try to remove the refresh_token which the device I want to force log out in database, and when the access_token and id_token was expired, I use the device to call the protected api, the website redirect to Auth website page because the access_token is expired. It was correct. But after that, Auth server always generate the Authorization_code and id_token although the refresh_token is already removed. Because of the id_token was generated, the website redirect to MVC website page and then the MVC server call the Auth Server in background. And!! The Auth server generate the access_token and return to the MVC server.
It means the MVC website refresh the access_token doesn't required the refresh_token!! 
I am very confuse why the Authorize Endpoint doesn't validate the refresh_token is exist? is it correct? 
If it is correct, how can I force log out other's device? I was stuck here very long time ,please help!!

Answer (score 0):

> But after that, Auth server always generate the Authorization_code and id_token although the refresh_token is already removed.

Thats because your user is still logged in on the IdentityServer4 webpage and has a valid cookie. The refresh token is only used by your MVC app to get new access tokens.

> It means the MVC website refresh the access_token doesn't required the refresh_token!!
> No. When the token expires, you get unauthorized (when MVC calls identity server for a new access token).

The user is redirected to IdSrv, where he is already logged in and since the user authorized the application (he gave his consent on the first login to allow this application to access his data), he isn't asked again and just gets the token and gets back to your application.

There, the new refresh token and code is used to receive an access token.

> If it is correct, how can I force log out other's device? I was stuck here very long time ,please help!!
> You need to implement some code in your IdSrv4 application, which tracks different device logins and invalidate this specific one.

Also from your MVC app you can signout the user from IdSrv4 too, when you pass a identity server token as hint.

From [IdSrv4 Docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html)

> #### id_token_hint
>
> When the user is redirected to the endpoint, they will be prompted if they really want to sign-out. This prompt can be bypassed by a client sending the original id_token received from authentication. This is passed as a query string parameter called id_token_hint.

This should invalidate the users cookie on IdSrv4 application.

If that doesn't work you'll have to add this functionality to IdSrv4 application to invalidate a specific cookie session (from the device you want to log out)

Comment: thank you first. The access_token was expired ! event though the cookies was exists and valid, but not useful !

Comment: when the access_token expired, it should go to idSrv and use refresh_token to request a new access_token(in this grantType, it doesn't request the access_token, it's request the authorize_code and id_token).

Comment: the use not want to sign out the current website in the device, he wants to force sign out the website in another device or browser. so, it's difficult call the MVC client to sign out the website in another device.

Comment: I also use the idSrv provided api called Revoke to remove the persisted refresh_token, there is same phenomenon.

Comment: I think you don't understand the underlying problem. The problem is not that the refresh token is revoked or access token expired. The problem is, that the user still has a valid sign in Cookie within your IdSrv4 application. When the refresh token isn't valid anymore the  MVC redirects the user to the identity server to obtain a new one. But because the user is logged in the Identity Server (do not matter if he is logged in your application or not), the token is issued immediately (without asking for user consent or credentials, because its not necessary since he is signed in)

Comment: You will need to invalidate this devices cookie in the IdSrv4 application (not in your MVC), for that you need to add additional Data when the user signs in with IdSrv4 to the Database (i.e. his location, IP, Computername, Time he was logged in) so he can identify that this session is the one from his other device. Then you invalidate this session (by deleting the entry from the session database). Next time this device is your identity server, it won't be logged in and also can't get a new refresh token without the users credentials

Comment: yes, I know the point. The cookies still exist in idSrv4 domain. I was remove the cookies and when then access_token expired, it will direct to the login form and required text username and password.

Comment: I know clean the cookies can  force log out,but how to clean other devices' cookies.
I know the refresh_token store in  persistedgrants table. I also clean all the data and restart the idSrv4, it doesn't working!  
As you said, the browser exist a cookies which contains an expired access_token, it will alway be valid and can access the protected API very long time. What is the refresh_token value of existence? refresh_token doesn't use for generate a new and not expired access_token?

Comment: The access_token contains in cookies is expired, strictly speaking the token doesn't valid, but it was valid before! If it was valid after it expire, why the browser redirect to idSrv4?